# Is it safe to remove .NET 5 runtime if .NET 6 runtime is installed?

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-5

From a purely user perspective, I am not developing applications on Windows, I merely install and uninstall stuff.

Microsoft Defender tells me that the installed .NET 5 installation is end of service. There is also a .NET 6 runtime installed.

So, is it safe to remove the .NET 5 runtime? Is there any way to tell which applications might be affected by the removal of .NET 5?

Comment: The safe thing to do is leave it alone. If it bothers you having an out of date runtime ... you can just remove it (and see if anything breaks). But if your plan is to reinstall it if you need ... make sure you can do that (sometimes you can no longer download unsupported .NET runtimes anymore from Microsoft!). This is kind of new territory - .NET 5 was a short-lived release. Application developers or users who aren't prepared to upgrade their apps should try to stick to LTS (Long term support) versions - the even numbered .NET releases.

Comment: But is it really safe(r) though? Even if none of my applications use the .net-5 anymore; it's presence might still enable some malware to exploit its weaknesses. While this is really some worst-case line of thinking; one might also be inclined to remove unused stuff purely from a house-keeping point of view. Why waste disk space for a run-time that's superfluous? As I see it right now, I have no way to tell whether the .net-5 is still used by anything, and Defender counts it as a weakness.

Comment: It may break something that depends on it if you remove  - that's not safe if by safe you mean will anything break if I remove it. This was how I was thinking of safe - sorry if I misinterpreted. I don't know of any way to tell what application might be depending on a specific version of .Net such as .Net 5 ... so unfortunately the only advice I can give is as in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to uninstall .net 5, take your time till you move/upgrade your application for .net 6

Microsoft defender is just warning you that .net 5 won't be getting any update,fixes or any support but still you can use it.

> Though it is good idea to move to lates technology due to security
> reasons.

If you have source code for your application, just goto 'cproj' file and version of .net is mentioned there like below

```
      <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> ****HERE****
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      </PropertyGroup>
      </Project>
```

After then build your project. You will get warning about depricated methods and all that you can fix it accordingly. Thats all....

If you are using third party application then you need to ask provider for updated version if there is.

Comment: I have no source code at all, I am merely an ordinary user who occasionally installs software. My guess is, that some application brought along .net-5 as dependency, and thus it was installed. With package management on Linux, you can tell which package is dependent on which packages, and there ought to be way to find out if library X is listed as a dependency of any of your installed packages. However, with Windows I guess there is no way to check whether anything still installed on my machine actually depends on the .net-5 runtime.

Comment: @DohnJoe if you are installing in windows using wizard then it will install all the dependency that is required. And as per you query to check what are the dependency there is no way to do that; not in my knowledge. ALthough you can always go to the developers of it and may be check on their website or somthing.